# iOS7 - Reachability not working?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, reachability

I am using Apple Reachability v3.0.
Apple rejected my app because this is not working in iOS 7.0.3 on iPhone 5s.

> We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPhone 5s running iOS 7.0.3, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we found that your app displays the error message: "No Internet Connection" after the user login.

this error message is not displayed on a device running iOS7.

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Who told you it is related to "Reachability"? The information you posted only says your app has bugs.

Comment: Oh Sorry!
it also says:
"Specifically, we found that your app displays the error message: "No Internet Connection" after the user login."

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

Instead of using Reachability provided by Apple, I used AFNetworking Reachability.
Now, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Apple rejected your app for being broken in some way.

Try following up with them asking for more information about the problems they ran into. They'll probably be able to provide some information about what they were seeing. Fix those problems and resubmit and you should be all good to go.

Comment: They say: "Specifically, we found that your app displays the error message: "No Internet Connection" after the user login."

And the message is not displayed in iPhone 5s(64-bit).
On further investigation I found that Reachability is not working on iPhone 5s, "when internet goes off, but notifies when internet gets back on again"

Comment: I just realised that it happens on any device running iOS7

Comment: That sounds like a problem that needs fixing!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NSURLSession` for maintaining the network connection. This is introduced in `iOS 7` so its easy to manage your checks and tasks.